# DJ-Stripe metadata not attaching to product

Tags: django, stripe-payments, metadata

I am following this guide:

https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/django-stripe-integrate/#contents

I get to "Adding metadata to your Stripe objects" and am told to create a metadata.py file. It doesn't tell me where to import @dataclass and List from so I had to guess. The issue is that, moving forward from this point in the guide, the metadata does not print to my template but I can retrieve product information. I'm thinking this guide is missing or assuming I know stuff about metadata that is required to make it work.

my metadata.py:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from pip import List
from project.subscriptions import features

@dataclass
class ProductMetadata(object):
    """
    Metadata for a Stripe product.
    """
    stripe_id: str
    name: str
    features: List[str]
    description: str = ''
    is_default: bool = False


PREMIUM = ProductMetadata(
    stripe_id='<prod id>',
    name='Premium',
    description='yerp',
    is_default=False,
    features=[
        features.UNLIMITED_WIDGETS,
        features.LUDICROUS_MODE,
        features.PRIORITY_SUPPORT,
    ],
)
```

features.py:

```
UNLIMITED_WIDGETS = 'Unlimited Widgets'
LUDICROUS_MODE = 'Ludicrous Mode'
PRIORITY_SUPPORT = 'Priority Support'
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from djstripe.models import Product

def pricing_page(request):
  context = {
    'products': Product.objects.all()
  }
  return render(request,'subscriptions/pricing_page.html', context=context)
```

urls:

```
path('pricing_page/', view=pricing_page, name='pricing_page'),
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{% load static socialaccount %}

{% block content %}

        <h1>Plans</h1>
       

        <section>
          <p class="title">Pricing Plans</p>
          <div class="columns">
            {% for product in products %}
              <div class="column">
                <p class="subtitle">{{ product.name }}</p>
                {% for plan in product.plan_set.all %}
                  <div>
                    <p class="heading">{{ plan.nickname }}</p>
                    <p>{{ plan.human_readable_price }}</p>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </section>

        
        <div class="plan-interval-selector">
          {% for plan in plans %}
            <button class="button">{{ plan.name }}</button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="columns plan-selector">
          {% for product in products %}
            {{ product.metadata|pprint }}

            <div class="column">
              <div {% if product.metadata.is_default %}class="is-selected"{% endif %}>
                <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fa {% if product.metadata.is_default %}fa-check{% else %}fa-circle{% endif %}">
                  </i>
                </span>
                <p class="plan-name">{{ product.metadata.name }}</p>
                <p class="plan-description">{{ product.metadata.description }}</p>
                <div class="plan-price">
                  <span class="price">{{ product.metadata.monthly_price }}</span> / month
                </div>
                <ul class="features">
                  {% for feature in product.metadata.features %}
                  <li>
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span class="feature">{{ feature }}</span>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The first forloop gets attributes directly from the product and it works. The second one tries to get the attributes from the metadata. It loops for each product but does not output the metadata. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried removing .metadata from your template to see if you can call name, description, features, etc. directly?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't do the trick...

Comment: Oh of course because the class isn't linked to the model - the author mentions linking the stripe_id but doesn't actually say how. It's possible the model has a method that gets the metadata class, or they might be using the django-metadata package https://github.com/thoas/django-metadata

Comment: Have you found a solution to this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def pricing_page(request):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        for product in products:
            if product.id == metadata.Starter.stripe_id:
                product.metadata = metadata.Starter
            elif product.id == metadata.Growth.stripe_id:
                product.metadata = metadata.Growth
            elif product.id == metadata.Advanced.stripe_id:
                product.metadata = metadata.Advanced
        
        return render(request, "home/pricing_page.html", ({'products': products }))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**